# vsCode Add Method Description to Custom Methods: C# / Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

When using vsCode, hovering over a built-in Method with your mouse will show a little pop-up window, where the method, return type and parameters are displayed. There usually also is a quick description, as to how the method works or what it does.

I want to add a description like that to my methods, but I can't seem to find how. Please Help.

I am working on a 3D Game in Unity, using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags) on your source code, e.g.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private object Method(object parameter)
{
    // ...
}
```

In Visual Studio, you just type the three slashes and it automatically adds that template. I'm guessing that VS Code might need more manual intervention.

EDIT: Seems like VS Code might be able to lend a helping hand, according to [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/c-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-code/). It says:

> In order to enable them, we need to enable the configuration **Format On Type** on *File->Preferences->Settings->Text Editor->Formatting*